# Screen Size in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, screen-size, game-development

Hello I am making a game in Java and I get the screenSize using DefaultToolkit, but the problem with that is that is detects the size of the screen if it was FULLSCREEN. How can I get the screen size of the area the game screen (which is not fullscreen) takes up.  To be more precise, my sprite is moving beyond the edge of the bottom screen because of the system tool bar which add extra "padding" to it.  How can I get the size of the Area the Game Screen takes up?  Thank you very much

Comment: Use [`Frame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29) and then `gameScreen.getSize()` for the dimensions of the painting area.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Assuming the frame is undecorated, otherwise you'd want to use the container's size

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I was presuming `gameScreen` was the 'game rendering/painting area' the OP extended from `JComponent` or `JPanel` to add to (or set  as) the content pane of the frame.  Though perhaps I should have made that more clear. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson is now :D

Answer (score 3):

I think Screen Bounds is what you are looking for:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameInfo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
        System.out.println("Screen Bounds: " + bounds );

        GraphicsDevice screen = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        GraphicsConfiguration config = screen.getDefaultConfiguration();
        System.out.println("Screen Size  : " + config.getBounds());
        System.out.println(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Info");
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible( true );

        System.out.println("Frame Size   : " + frame.getSize() );
        System.out.println("Frame Insets : " + frame.getInsets() );
        System.out.println("Content Size : " + frame.getContentPane().getSize() );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the size of the task bar and other things using Insets. Here's an example to get the screen size that doesn't include the task bar/others.

```
// Screen size
Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

// Screen insets
Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration());

// Get the real width/height
int width = screen.getWidth() - insets.left - insets.right;
int height = screen.getHeight() - insets.top - insets.bottom;
```

Comment: Assuming the window the OP is using is undecorated, otherwise you'd want to simply use the container's size.  But this could be used to set the size of the window in the first place +1