# How to get a jframe to take up the whole screen without covering the taskbar in widows 10

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windows-10

So I have my JFrame and I have it to the size of my screen, but the bottom[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9hlE.png) portion gets stuck under my task bar. (See screenshot)

Does anyone know how i could do this? I want to adjust the full screen size of my jframe to take the task-bar into account.

Comment: You probably want [setExtendedState()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState-int-) instead of setting width/height yourself

Comment: you can go to full screen mode by applying frame.setUndecorated(true); This way JFrame will go over the task bar.

Comment: @brainiac080195 "without covering the taskbar" ...

Comment: This question has been answered here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123735/get-effective-screen-size-from-java) and here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845886/screen-size-in-java)